# angularJS filter using array type(?) ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I wanna make filter working at only one element. 
To make filter, I searched SO, and find way to make it I want.
But I used 'select' tag to choose element applies to filter, I got problem when selected value is NULL.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="setParam">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="atName">Name</option>
        <option value="atComp">Company</option>
        <option value="atDep">Department</option>
        <option value="atPos">Position</option>
        <option value="atTel">Tel</option>
        <option value="atEmail">Email</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="atParam[setParam]">                               
    </span>

<tr data-ng-repeat="row in attendees | filter : atParam">
```

The problem is getting nothing to display when selected value is NULL.
Everything except NULL works well. What should do if I solve it?
Or, are there another ways to search? Thanks!

Comment: What should `null` mean?

Comment: what does `atParam` contain

Comment: atParam is input text box. Null means first search option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your requirement is when you select `ALL` all the records should be displayed. But you are getting none.

For that you need to add a `condition` to the `filter` depending on the `setParam`

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in attendees | filter : setParam ? atParam : ''">
```

What this does is,

- It will search for setParam first.
- If it is `not null` then the `atParam` condition of yours is used.
- If it is null then, the `empty string` is filtered thereby displaying `all records`

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I can't get idea how handle setPram when it is null.